# How can I solve this problem? "Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: "

Tags: excel, grails, export, tags

It seems like it´s not getting the right method or siganture. It has already worked for a long time, but yeterday I got this Error and I don´t know where I can start.

I reinstalled the plugin "export 0.3" and I installed the newest Verion "export 0.6". All  attempts  were  in  vain. I´m using Grails 1.2, Groovy 1.7 and export 0.6. Here´s the full Error Message and Stacktrace. Thanks for getting back to me as soon as possible.

**My code for the export:**

```
<export:formats formats="['excel']" action="exportTable" params="${params}"/>
```

**Error Message an Stacktrace**

```
**Grails Runtime Exception
Error Details**
Message: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82]
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82] at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:56 at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:326
Class: ExportTagLib
At Line: [45]
Code Snippet:
Stack Trace

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82] at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:56 at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:326

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:form>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82] at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:56 at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:326

 at C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp:145)

 at C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp)

 at C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp.run(C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp:158)

 ... 1 more

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82] at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:56

 ... 4 more

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <export:formats>: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82] at C:/WORK/sts/CENcon/grails-app/views/analysisConsumption/list.gsp:56

 at C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp$_run_closure2_closure15.doCall(C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp:55)

 at C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp$_run_closure2_closure15.doCall(C__WORK_sts_CENcon_grails_app_views_analysisConsumption_list_gsp)

 ... 4 more

    Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82]

     ... 6 more

    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageAttributes, de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3) values: [[class:export], de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1_closure3@1a3fa82]

     at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportTagLib$_closure1.doCall(ExportTagLib.groovy:45)

     ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your GSP page and add the following markup to your GSP header: `<export:resource />`     (necessary to use the export features).

Check also if you add MimeTypes for CSV, Excel, ODS, PDF and RTF to grails-app/conf/Config.groovy.

Note : last release is 0.7.
More details : http://www.grails.org/plugin/export

Comment: I already had the tag in my header "<export:resource />". Haven´t found any solution so I reinitialed my old version and put all changes by hand into the old version and it works again with the export 0.3. Thank you for your suggestion!